# Fortran code won't write to file

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I am working on a program to calculate minimum nozzle length in supersonic nozzles (Method of Characteristics). I can't seem to figure out why my code won't write to my output file (the lines "write (6,1000)....). My code is below:

```
      program tester
c----------------------------------------------------------------------c
      implicit real (a-h,o-z)
      integer count
      real kminus(0:100),kplus(0:100),theta(0:100),nu(0:100),mach(0:100)
     +     ,mu(0:100)
      open (5,file='tester.in')
      open (6,file='tester.out')
      read (5,*) me
      read (5,*) maxturn
      read (5,*) nchar
      read (5,*) theta0
      close(5)
c.....set count to 0 and calculate dtheta
      count=0
      dtheta=(maxturn-theta0)/nchar
c.....first characteristic
      do 10 an=1,nchar+1
         count=count+1
c........these are already known
         theta(count)=theta0+dtheta*(an-1)
         nu(count)=theta(count)
c........trivial, but we will "calculate" them anyways
         kminus(count)=2*theta(count)
         kplus(count)=0
c........we feed it nu(count) and get m out
         call pm_hall_approx(nu(count),m)
         mach(count)=m
c........does not work with sqrt(...) for some reason
         mu(count)=atan((1/(mach(count)**2)-1)**0.5)
         write (6,1000) count,kminus(count),kplus(count),theta(count)
     +                  ,nu(count),mach(count),mu(count)
   10 continue
c.....the other characteristics
      do 30 bn=1,nchar
         do 20 cn=1,(nchar+1-bn)
            count=count+1
c...........these are given
            kminus(count)=kminus(cn+bn)
            kplus(count)=-1*kplus(bn+1)
c...........if this is the last point, copy the previous values
            if (cn.eq.(nchar+1-bn)) then
               kminus(count)=kminus(count-1)
               kplus(count)=kplus(count-1)
            endif
c...........calculate theta and nu
            theta(count)=0.5*(kminus(count)+kplus(count))
            nu(count)=0.5*(kminus(count)-kplus(count))
c...........calculate m
            call pm_hall_approx(nu(count),m)
            mach(count)=m
            mu(count)=atan((1/(mach(count)**2)-1)**0.5)
            write (6,1000) count,kminus(count),kplus(count),theta(count)
     +                     ,nu(count),mach(count),mu(count)
   20    continue
   30 continue
      close(6)
      stop
 1000 format (11(1pe12.4))
      end
c======================================================================c

      include 'pm_hall_approx.f'
```

And my subroutine is given here:

```
      subroutine pm_hall_approx(nu,mach)
c----------------------------------------------------------------------c
c     Given a Mach number, use the Hall Approximation to calculate the 
c     Prandtl-Meyer Function.
c----------------------------------------------------------------------c
      implicit real (a-h,o-z)
c.....set constants
      parameter (a=1.3604,b=0.0962,c=-0.5127,d=-0.6722,e=-0.3278)
      parameter (numax=2.2769)
      y=nu/numax
      mach=(1+a*y+b*y*y+c*y*y*y)/(1+d*y+e*y*y)
      return
      end
```

And here are the contents of tester.in

```
 2.4     = mache
 5.0     = maxturn
 7       = nchar
 0.375    = theta0
```

Comment: what is the contents of `tester.in`?.

Comment: Added @m-chinoune. Ch. Thanks!

Comment: @M.Chinoune Thanks!

Comment: you have a bad program and input file. you must declare the variables `me` and `maxturn` to be real or change the input data to `2 = mache` and `5 = maxturn`. The second thing : the variable `count` is integer, so you can't use real format to write it, so change the format to `1000 format (i0,2x,10(1pe12.4))`. and Please change the loops indexes to integer.

Comment: @M.Chinoune

Thank you so, SO much. This is my first program in Fortran. It's been an uphill struggle for the past 2 days.

Comment: The real lesson you should learn is always to use Implicit None and type all your variables.

Comment: Indeed, nu, mach, and numax are treated implicitly as integers in pm_hall_approx(), so very likely giving a wrong result... (They are probably real, and also the actual argument 'm' etc probably needs to be real.) "implicit none" is really helpful to find such problems of types.

Comment: everytime somebody writes a program with implicit types and in fixed form fortran, a kitten dies...

Comment: Implicit none. Got the tip :)

Answer (score 0):

In fortran, unit number 6 is reserved for screen. Never use that as the unit number. Try changing it to some other number like `write(7,1000)` and then it should work.

Comment: @francescalus: Probably I am bad at using the correct words then. See [this](http://www.oc.nps.edu/~bird/oc3030_online/fortran/io/io.html).

Comment: @francescalus, Many compilers reserve unit=6 for output, just try`use iso_fortran_env ; print*,output_unit`

Comment: @M.Chinoune, `output_unit` refers simply to a particular preconnected unit.  Many compilers may indeed use `6` for this but there is still no concept of _reserving_ it.  Like any other preconnected unit it may have its connection changed in an `open` statement.

Comment: I changed it to write(7,1000), but I'm still not getting an output. I'm using g77 if that makes a difference.

Comment: Did your program run to completion?  If so then you are certain the code got to the write statement.  I'd add an additional write statement directly before your write(7,1000) statement.  Make this write statement 'write(6,1000) or write(*,1000). Either one should write to screen. If it doesn't, you code doesn't make it that far and hence, you have a different problem.